# Trouble clearing column in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My aim is to clear a pointer column on a parse object:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query.get("myobjectid").then(function(o) {
    o.pointerColumn = undefined;
    return o.save();
}).then(function() {
    var query2 = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
    return query2.get("myobjectid");
}).then(function(o) {
    alert(o.pointerColumn);
});
```

The alert (and the data browser) shows me that the column value still exists.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that Parse.Object provides a method called `unset` to make the value of a column undefined.  My code, rewritten to work looks like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query.get("myobjectid").then(function(o) {
    o.unset("pointerColumn");
    return o.save();
}).then(function() {
    var query2 = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
    return query2.get("myobjectid");
}).then(function(o) {
    alert(o.pointerColumn);  // alerts undefined, as expected
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line sets the property value to `undefined`, like any other assignment operator would set a value.

```
o.pointerColumn = undefined;
```

Instead, use `delete` to completely remove the property from the `o` object:

```
delete o.pointerColumn;
return o.save();
```

Comment: thanks.  is that the right syntax on the delete (for js)?  can't find it in the docs

Comment: @danh: Yes, it looks strange if you've never used it before, but that is the correct syntax for removing a property from an existing object.

Comment: thanks again for the help on this.  delete didn't work (still not even sure how it compiles), but Parse.Object unset did work, i.e. o.unset("pointerColumn");  do you want to edit your answer?  I'd like to mark it correct since it helped me get on the right track.

Comment: I think I get it now.  delete is just regular JS to remove properties, but this won't work with my parse objects.  They have their properties buried a level deeper, and my pointerColumn is a getter function that I built to alias o.get("pointerColumn").  So delete is probably not the solution for parse.com (meanwhile unset works fine).

Comment: @danh: I see. I'm unfamiliar with the parse.com library. Since you found the answer, I would just answer your own question and then accept it.